# Ford Taurus Grinding Sound Slowed Movement

Tags: ford, taurus, grinding

Not sure what is going on, but my 2009 Ford Taurus SE is acting up. It feels as though I'm losing power and unable to accelerate, and some times it grinds and the traction control light flickers. The grinding sounds like it could be coming from the area near the wheel, but I can't be certain. I'm not sure how to better describe it other than maybe the drivers side front wheel feels locked. Any ideas of what could be wrong would be most appreciated.